# Wrangle data from long to wide format for cox regression in R

Tags: r, dataframe, cox-regression, wrangle

I am trying to wrangle some data for a cox regression...

```
#generate some data
set.seed(1)
ID <- sort(rep(1:10, times = 5))
conditions <- rep(c("asthma", "copd", "af", "cvd", "ckd"), times = 10)
day <- sample(1:100, 50)

#assign to dataframe
df <- data.frame(ID, conditions, day)
```

I have data in a long format like this:

| ID | conditions | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | asthma | 68 |
| 1 | copd | 39 |
| 1 | af | 1 |
| 1 | cvd | 34 |
| 1 | ckd | 87 |
| 2 | asthma | 43 |
| 2 | copd | 14 |
| 2 | af | 82 |
| 2 | cvd | 59 |
| 2 | ckd | 51 |

And I need it wrangled to this:
As you can see, ID=1 develops AF on day 1, cvd on day 34 and copd on day 39… 
So assuming that this is in order of date…
In rownum 1, the af column changes to 1…
In rownum 2, the af AND cvd changes to 1…
In rownum3, the af AND cvd AND copd changes to 1…
Then it would be the same kind of pattern for all the other IDs.

| rownum | ID | day | asthma | copd | af | cvd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 34 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 39 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 68 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 14 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 43 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 2 | 51 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| … | … | … | … | … | … | … |

I've tried using a lag function, but it just doesn't work... the lag needs to work for multiple columns as you can see above.

```
dt[,temp:=ifelse(is.na(reglag(event_dt,1)), as.integer(0), reglag(event_dt,1)), by=ID]
dt[, sequence:=cumsum(temp)+1, by=ID]

func = function(x)
{
  which(c(1,lag(x,1)[-1]) %in% 1) %>%
    c(length(x)+1) %>% 
    diff
}

reglag = function(x,lag) {c(rep(NA,lag), x[lag:(length(x)-1)])}

dt[, cond.time:=func(event_dt) %>% lapply(seq) %>% unlist, by=ID]
```

Would be very grateful for any help you could give.  I also have a massive table, so maybe a loop would cause me memory issues...

Many many thanks in advance
~R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrange` by ID and day, and `pivot_wider`. You'll get `1` for the disease at day d, `0` elsewhere. Use `cumsum` to add 1 to the consecutive values for each column.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(ID, day) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = conditions, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(af:ckd, cumsum))
```

output

```r
     ID   day    af   cvd  copd asthma   ckd
   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     0     0      0     0
 2     1    34     1     1     0      0     0
 3     1    39     1     1     1      0     0
 4     1    68     1     1     1      1     0
 5     1    87     1     1     1      1     1
 6     2    14     0     0     1      0     0
 7     2    43     0     0     1      1     0
 8     2    51     0     0     1      1     1
 9     2    59     0     1     1      1     1
10     2    82     1     1     1      1     1
# … with 40 more rows
```

Comment: One more question though, Mael.... your last line -  mutate(across(af:ckd, cumsum))... Is there any way that I could get these values af and ckd from the original "conditions" column rather than defining these manually in this last line?

Comment: You could get `un <- unique(df$conditions)` and do `across(un)`